# flutter canvas custom transparent

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to choose a color to be replaced for transparent when painting an image to the Flutter canvas? I have a spritesheet with magenta background and I want it to be transparent when painted. I am painting in the following way:

```dart
  void _draw(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ui.Image image) {
    final paint = Paint();
    canvas.drawImage(image, offset, paint);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set an ARGB color with the alpha value

```
paint.color = Color.fromARGB(alpha, r, g, b)
```

Where alpha is a double between 0 and 1, 0 being transparent and 1 the most visible. R,G,B is the level of red blue green colors applied.

The white color is:

```
r=255, g=255, b=255
```

The black color is:

```
r=0, g=0, b=0
```

So in your case:

```
paint.color = Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: This changes the opacity of the whole image. What I am trying to achieve is, where the pixel is magenta, paint it as transparent.